# Other options menu items not showing after expanded searchview is collapsed

Tags: android, searchview, android-optionsmenu

I have a simple activity with options menu setup with the code shown below. The problem i'm experiencing is that after expanding and collapsing the searchview, menu items with `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` do not appear, even though there is room on the toolbar. Menu items with `app:showAsAction="never"` on the other hand do appear.

menu_simple_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_filter"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_sort"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_print_all"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_print_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/action_print_all"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

SimpleActivity.java

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_simple_activity, menu);
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final MenuItem filterMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter);
        final MenuItem sortMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort);
        final MenuItem printAllMenuItem = 
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_print_all);

        searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new 
        MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                filterMenuItem.setVisible(false);
                sortMenuItem.setVisible(false);
                printAllMenuItem.setVisible(false);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                filterMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                sortMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                printAllMenuItem.setVisible(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

How do i fix it?

Comment: have you tried calling [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) ?

Comment: Calling invalidateOptionsMenu() after enabling visibility of the other items works. Thanks

Comment: I'll write an answer so you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()) after setting the items as visible.

From the documentation:

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The
>   onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs
>   to be displayed.